# Why is it justified to take the infimum on both sides of this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, solution-verification, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $A\subset \Bbb R$ and we define, $f(x)=\inf \{|x-a|:a\in A\}.$

**Claim:** $f$ is continuous everywhere on $\Bbb R.$

We fix $a\in A$ and let $x\in \Bbb R$ be any arbitrary real number. Then, $f(x)\leq |x-a|\leq |x-y|+|y-a|$ for some arbitrary $y\in \Bbb R.$

Now, taking infimum on both sides of the above inequality we have, $f(x)\leq |x-y|+f(y).$

This means $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$ from the symmetry.

Let $c\in \Bbb R.$

So, if $\epsilon\gt 0$ we take, $|x-c|\lt \epsilon$ then, we have, $|f(x)-f(c)|\lt \epsilon.$

This means, $f$ is continuous in $c.$ As, $c$ is arbitrary, our claim is proved.

---

But now, I have a much more fundamental question. How is the step where we take the infimum on both sides of the inequality $f(x)\leq |x-a|\leq |x-y|+|y-a|$ justified? I mean, I am not sure why can we write,  $f(x)\leq |x-y|+f(y)$ from here, precisely?

Although $f(x)\leq |x-y|+|y-a|$ holds for all $a\in A,$ we aren't sure that it holds when $|y-a|$ is replaced by $f(y)$ because *there might not exist an $a'\in A$ such that $$f(y)=\inf\{|y-a|:a\in A\}=|y-a'|$$.* This is the part which makes the thing complicated.

Comment: You need to fix both $x$ and $y$, and vary $a\in A$ in the inequality $f(x) \leq |x-y| + |y-a|$. Then, the LHS remains fixed while you take an infimum on the RHS.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Although $f(x)\leq |x-y|+|y-a|$ holds for all $a\in A,$ we aren't sure that it holds when $|y-a|$ is replaced by $f(y)$ because *there might not exist an $a'\in A$ such that $$f(y)=\inf\{|y-a|:a\in A\}=|y-a'|$$.* This is the part which makes the thing complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" *Although $f(x)\leq |x-y|+|y-a|$ holds for all $a\in A,$ we aren't sure that it holds when $|y-a|$ is replaced by $f(y)$ because there might not exist an $a'\in A$ such that*$$f(y)=\inf\{|y-a|:a\in A\}=|y-a'|."$$

You don't need such an $a'.$ Simply note that by the definition of the infimum (*greatest* lower bound), if $c$ is a lower bound for some set $E,$ i.e.

> if $$\forall e\in E\quad c\le e$$
> then $$c\le\inf(E).$$

Apply this to $c=f(x)-|x-y|$ and $E=\{|y-a|:a\in A\}$ for $x$ and $y$ fixed.

Alternatively, apply it to $c=f(x)$ and $E=\{|x-y|+ |y-a|:a\in A\},$ as advised by @PrahladVaidyanathan in the first comment above, and use that $\inf\{d+f:f\in F\}=d+\inf(F).$